# What about JavaOs?

Tags: java, operating-system

Whenever I asked someone "Is it possible to write an operating system in Java?"their answers were negative,as Java requires a virtual machine.
But what about JavaOs http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaOS 
According to Wikipedia it was developed in Java!
How did they succeeded that?

Comment: The entire Java virtual machine can be implemented in hardware -- as in various [Java processors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_processor).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to make an operating system using java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1988196/is-it-possible-to-make-an-operating-system-using-java)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Wikipedia article answers your question: *JavaOS is primarily written in Java* – that means it is not entirely written in Java, but: *The system is based on a hardware architecture native microkernel. The Java virtual machine runs on top of the microkernel.*

Comment: It looks like I have to learn english more,thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The term Java is ambiguous; it's the name of a programming language and it's the name of a runtime environment. The two are typically closely coupled because most of the time, the Java programming language is compiled into a binary format called bytecode which is intended to be run within the Java Virtual Machine environment.

That being the case, it's certainly possible to write code using the Java language which is compiled to any other binary format. Decouple the language from where it runs (as is trivial to do in this case) and Java (as a language) becomes just another language that can be used to develop the same things any other generic language can.