# Why operating systems are not written in java?

Tags: java

All the operating systems till date have been written in C/C++ while there is none in Java. There are tonnes of Java applications but not an OS. Why?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaOS

Comment: Plenty of operating systems have been written in languages other than C or C++. People were writing operating systems *before* C and C++. Java seems like a particularly poor choice for this use case, though.

Comment: There has been Jx. Strangely enough, Java with it's mutable object instances and black and white security implemented through *class loading* and things like integer overflows would not be secure *enough* for me to recommend it for implementing a secure OS, which it seems best fitted for at first glance.

Answer (score 12):

Because we have operating systems already, mainly. Java isn't designed to run on bare metal, but that's not as big of a hurdle as it might seem at first. As C compilers provide intrinsic functions that compile to specific instructions, a Java compiler (or JIT, the distinction isn't meaningful in this context) could do the same thing. Handling the interaction of GC and the memory manager would be somewhat tricky also. But it could be done. The result is a kernel that's 95% Java and ready to run jars. What's next?

Now it's time to write an operating system. Device drivers, a filesystem, a network stack, all the other components that make it possible to do things with a computer. The Java standard library normally leans heavily on system calls to do the heavy lifting, both because it has to and because *running a computer is a pain in the ass*. Writing a file, for example, involves the following layers (at least, I'm not an OS guy so I've surely missed stuff):

1. The filesystem, which has to find space for the file, update its directory structure, handle journaling, and finally decide what disk blocks need to be written and in what order.
2. The block layer, which has to schedule concurrent writes and reads to maximize throughput while maximizing fairness.
3. The device driver, which has to keep the device happy and poke it in the right places to make things happen. And of course every device is broken in its own special way, requiring its own driver.

And all this has to work fine and remain performant with a dozen threads accessing the disk, because a disk is essentially an enormous pile of shared mutable state.

At the end, you've got Linux, except it doesn't work as well because it doesn't have near as much effort invested into functionality and performance, and it only runs Java. Possibly you gain performance from having a single address space and no kernel/userspace distinction, but the gain isn't worth the effort involved.

There is one place where a language-specific OS makes sense: VMs. Let the underlying OS handle the hard parts of running a computer, and the tenant OS handles turning a VM into an execution environment. [BareMetal](https://github.com/ReturnInfinity/BareMetal-OS) and [MirageOS](http://openmirage.org) follow this model. Why would you bother doing this instead of using Docker? That's a good question.

Answer (score 4):

Indeed there is a JavaOS http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaOS

And here is discuss about why there is not many OS written in java [Is it possible to make an operating system using java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1988196/is-it-possible-to-make-an-operating-system-using-java)

In short, Java need to run on JVM. JVM need to run on an OS. writing an OS using Java is not a good choice.

OS needs to deal with hardware which is not doable using java (except using JNI). And that is because JVM only provided limited commands which can be used in Java. These command including add, call a method and so on. But deal with hardware need command to operate reg, memory, CPU, hardware drivers directly. These are not supported directly in JVM so JNI is needed. That is back to the start - it is still needed to write an OS using C/assembly.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Seems like this should be a comment. Also, JavaOS is discontinued

Comment: In my opinion, having to use assembly for parts of your OS doesn't negate the fact that the rest of the OS *is* written in another language (Java, C#, etc). I've yet to see an OS (even a C or C++ based one) that *doesn't* contain at least a little bit of assembly code. It hardly takes the whole thing "back to the start". Also, keep in mind: there's nothing preventing you from compiling Java to machine code.

Comment: I remember that at the end of 2000s, VMWare try to launch a techology that runs the JVM directly on an ESX server, w/out any SO in the middle.

Answer (score 3):

One of the main benefits of using Java is that abstracts away a lot of low level details that you usually don't really need to care about. It's those details which are required when you build an OS. So while you could work around this to write an OS in Java, it would have a lot of limitations, and you'd spend a lot of time fighting with the language and its initial design principles.

Answer (score 3):

For operating systems you need to work really low-level. And that is a pain in Java. You do need e.g. unsigned data types, and Java only has signed data types. You need `struct` objects that have exactly the memory alignment the driver expects (and no object header like Java adds to every object).

Even key components of Java itself are no longer written in Java.

And this is -by no means- a temporary thing. More and more does get rewritten in native code to get better performance. The HotSpot VM adds "intrinsics" for performance critical native code, and there is work underway to reduce the overall cost of native calls.

For example **JavaFX**: The reason why it is much faster than AWT/Swing ever were is because it contains/uses a huge amount of native code. It relies on native code for rendering, and e.g. if you add the "webview" browser component it is actually using the webkit C library to provide the browser.

There is a number of things Java does really well. It is a nicely structured language with a *fantastic* toolchain. Python is much more compact to write, but its toolchain is a mess, e.g. refactoring tools are disappointing. And where Java shines is at optimizing polymorphism at run-time. Where C++ compilers would need to do expensive virtual calls - because at compile time it is not known which implementation will be used - there Hotspot can aggressively inline code to get better performance. But for operating systems, you do not need this much. You can afford to manually optimize call sites and inlining.

Answer (score 1):

This answer does not mean to be exhaustive in any way, but I'd like to share my thoughts on the (very vast) topic.

Although it is theoretically possible to write some OS in pure java, there are practical matters that make this task really difficult. The main problem is that there is no (currently up to date and reliable) java compiler able to compile java to byte code. So there is no existing tool to make writing a whole OS from the ground up feasible in java, at least as far as my knowledge goes.

Java was designed to run in some implementation of the java virtual machine. There exist implementations for Windows, Mac, Linux, Android, etc. The design of the language is strongly based on the assumption that the JVM exists and will do some magic for you at runtime (think garbage collection, JIT compiler, reflection, etc.). This is most likely part of the reason why such a compiler does not exist: where would all these functionality go? Compiled down to byte code? It's possible but at this point I believe it would be difficult to do. Even Android, whose SDK is purely java based, runs Dalvik (a version of the JVM that supports a subset of the language) on a Linux Kernel.